# How to Give Button Exit Functionality in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I am designing two pages, one followed by the other, in Xcode 7. Let's call them the first and second view controllers. From a button in the first view controller, with a modal segue, the second view controller shows up. I want to add a button to second view controller so that when I hit that button, I can simply exit from the second and back to the first view controller.

I know this feature can be done by navigation controller with putting cancel button to the navigation bar on second view controller which I don't want to. I want specifically a button to have that functionality.

I thought of calling the first view controller with code when the button is tapped, but it sounds me like a bad coding. So, I would like to learn what is a good way of achieving this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add method to the second view controller:

```
@IBAction func exitButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
}
```

Next add button to the second view controller in interface builder and connect button's action to this method.

Comment: This sounds like what I'm looking for right now. Thanks, I will give the feedback when I try

Answer (score 2):

**use Unwind Segues**

> Unwind Segues give you a way to “unwind” the navigation stack and specify a destination to go back to.

for sample [tutorial1](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/), [tutorial2](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/12/01/program-ios-unwind-segue/)

Comment: That, I really liked. Thanks for the tutorial.